# Play video in android view using php URL

Tags: android

I have a link in the form

```
http://something.com/some/play.php
```

When I simply put and go on the browser, the video gets played. It is a live video.

I want to make request to this URL and then run the video in android view.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

With a `VideoView`, you should be able to do the following:

```
String path="http://something.com/some/play.php";

Uri uri=Uri.parse(path);

VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
video.start();
```

Check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) regarding VideoView, and [here's an example](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/) on how you can stream using VideoView.

Comment: What? Is that it? Are you sure?

Comment: I guess this works to urls like __http://something.com/some/play.mp4__

The one that is not php but real media